# The radius of the circle which just touches the outer circle

Tags: geometry, geometric-interpretation

Suppose two concentric circles with radius $a$ and $b\ (>a)$ and origin as their center.

[image]

I wanted to put another circle whose center lies in a line $x=a$ (that is red line) in such a way that it just touches the outer circle at a single point. Something like this

[image]

As an equation solving a problem we can solve
$$(x-a)^2+(y-r)^2=r^2$$
$$x^2+y^2=b^2$$
find the quadratic in $x$ and make the roots equal to each other. But that's too long a calculation, I wanted to know if I can solve it from the geometry of the figure. Or some much simpler method. **Mainly I'm interested in $r$**. Can any help me with this?

Comment: Hint: The common tangent is perpendicular to radii of both circles. So:
$r + \sqrt{a^2 + r^2} = b $

Comment: What's the role of the green circle in you rproblem?

Comment: @CiaPan  The red vertical line is a tangent to the green circle. But, then, we can draw the red line without drawing the green circle.

Comment: @CiaPan The $x$ coordinate of the center of the circle I need is equaled to the radius of the green one.

Comment: So, you used the green circle to draw a red line. But once the red line is drawn, the green circle is no longer necessary, right? We can forget the circle and take the line as a basis of the construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following is the idea commented by @Kaind, which uses geometry to solve the problem. By the way, By geometry, I don't mean taking scale and pencil and then go about taking measurements.

[image]

In triangle $\Delta ACD$
$$(AC)^2=a^2+r^2$$
Also
$$AC+CB=AB\Rightarrow \sqrt{a^2+r^2}+r=b$$
$$(a^2+r^2)=(b-r)^2$$
$$\boxed{r=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2b}}$$

Answer (score 0):

If the red circle is to touch the blue one, then both their centers and the tangency point lie on a common line. So, draw a line through the center of the blue circle. Its intersection with the red line defines a center of the red circle, and its intersection with the blue circle defines a tangency point. Their distance is a radius you need.

Comment: I don't need that on graph paper. I have to compute it, I mean value of the radius of an orange circle in terms of blue circle radius and green circle radius.

Comment: You said _'I wanted to know if I can solve it from the geometry of the figure.'_ This is a solution from geometry. If you want something else, then ask something else.

Comment: BTW, you can translate this geometric construction into algebra pretty easily. You just need to identify some free parameter in the construction and fix it, otherwise the solution is undetermined. It can be e.g. the ordinate of the new circle's center of one coordinate of the tangency point or a slope of the auxiliary line...